# How to render multiple cameras as separate image sequences?

Tags: rendering

I've got a shattering physics simulation that I'd like rendered from different angles.

Using the [stereoscopy method](https://youtu.be/mFSq0nUl-0YtJ-n0A820) seems to be the best so far but uses suffixes to differentiate cameras.  When attempting to import into After Effects each camera is considered the next frame and it's a mess. Using explorer or cmd code to move 1500 frames into different folders is an unfortunately time consuming process.

So next I tried scenes, duplicating the original as a linked copy, assigning it a camera and [using render nodes](https://youtu.be/LPneC8b6gnU?t=167) which allows you to give each camera a prefix.  This generates a usable list of png's which can be imported into AE correctly.  However not only does duplicating scenes add unnecessary complexity I've realized I also must bake physics for each scene before render.

I'm considering going back to stereoscopy method and hope I can do something tricky with file naming.  Unless someone else has a better suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: well, i don't know after effects but Blender will name them 0001_R.png 0002_R.png and so on (if you choose R as suffix) and 0001_L.png  and so on. So pretty logic i think. So i assume after effects takes them just in the order you select them? Can't you first import all _L and then import all _R ? it's just an assumption...as i said - i have no idea of ai

Comment: The best I can think of is still cumbersome:  Add and place your cameras.  Bake the physics.  Select one of the cameras, make it active, point render file output at a particular directory and render animation.  Select another, make it active, change render file output to a different directory and render animation.  On the other hand, you can use wildcards to move the files afterwards.  (cd dir1 ; mv *_R.png ../dir2) in bash. isn't that cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

### Tip 01_Search

I'm not sure about Win, but should be similar as on Mac - go to directory, let search for suffix (L/R), move all into separate folder ... done in two clicks.

### Tip 02_Video Editing

Create empty Scene, switch to Video Editing, add Scene Strip, under properties specify Camera 01, duplicate strip and move after the first one, change Camera object to second one.